# Приведение типов с помощью GetType()

Tags: c#, .net

Как совершить приведение типов, если конечный тип заранее неизвестен?

```
 T _view = sender as T;
 var VMtype = _view.DataContext.GetType();
 var vm = _view.DataContext as SecondViewModel;
```

Как вместо `SecondViewModel` указать тип, возращаемый `GetType`?

Comment: как ты дальше хочешь использовать vm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выглядит бессмысленно, но подобное преобразование можно делать с помощью `Convert.ChangeType`

`var vm = Convert.ChangeType(_view.DataContext, _view.DataContext.GetType());`

Comment: Почему бессмысленно ?

Comment: @СергейТрофимов конкретно в вашем случае это операция по сути ничего не делает :D

Comment: Я делаю универсальный метод, очистки контейнера IoC.
Для очистки контейнера мне нужно знать тип объекта, от которого я хочу его очистить .

Comment: Но спасибо за Ваш ответ. Мне помог.

Comment: _Выглядит бессмысленно_ - собственно не только выглядит :) и данную строчку вполне можно заменить следующей (в большинстве случаев): `object vm = _view.DataContext`

Comment: @Grundy соглашусь, в общем вопрос нормальный "как привести к заранее неизвестному типу получаемому с помощью GetType", но в конкретном взятом случае это вещь совсем уж странная)

Comment: @yolosora я не стал приводить свой код, это только запутает и отведет взгляд от основной моей задачи :) 
Представьте что мне нужно удалить из ArrayList объект какого-то определенного типа, который я не знаю за ранее. В общем у меня примерно такая задача была.

Comment: @СергейТрофимов, а мы точно о c# говорим? В нем уже давно от ArrayList  отказались, в пользу generics, ну и для сравнения приводить типы не надо, достаточно получить их